# После цикла for код дальше не выполняется. Как выйти из цикла?

Tags: java, массивы, for

Пытаюсь решить задачу: найти минимальное значение n-ной последовательности.Вроде ничего сложного, но программа не хочет ничего делать после первого цикла for. Подскажите пожалуйста, как выйти из цикла, когда массив уже заполнен.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] array = new int[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++) {
        array[i] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }

    int min = array[0];
    for(int i : array){
        if(min>array[i]){
            min = array[i];}
    }
    System.out.println(min);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл работает нормально, и отрабатывает, просто в консоль выводится введёное вами число, далее вам нужно ещё раз ввести число, на той же строке что и вывод.

Ещё в программе есть косяк. Ищите его в этом фрагменте

```
for(int i : array){
        if(min>array[i]){
            min = array[i];}
    }
```

А по поводу вопроса "как выйти из цикла?", для этого есть директивы break; и continue;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]